# "I am..., and am..." or "I am..., and I am..."

Tags: sentence-construction, parallelism, compound-subjects, conjunction-reduction

> A) I am eager to learn more about the position, and grateful for this opportunity to meet the sales team in person.
>
> B) I am eager to learn more about the position, and am grateful for this opportunity to meet the sales team in person.
>
> C) I am eager to learn more about the position, and I am grateful for this opportunity to meet the sales team in person.
>
> D) I am eager to learn more about the position and grateful for this opportunity to meet the sales team in person.

Questions:

1. Are any of the options above grammatically incorrect?
2. Which is the most correct?
3. And what is this concept of a shared subject across two clauses called? Parallelism? Conjunction reduction? It seems so basic but I don't remember the term for it.

Comment: I prefer A, because the relation of the predicates goes beyond their parallel structures.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like B. It sounds much better if the subject is repeated.
This shorter example,

> He is angry, and is waiting for you.

is not ungrammatical, but I think it is improved by repeating the subject:

> He's angry, and he's waiting for you.

Personally, I prefer example C, though I would contract "I am" to "I'm" in both places.